# Drawing multiple SVG lines side by side

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="250" height="250">
    <line x1="0"  y1="100" x2="0" y2="37" stroke="red" stroke-width="50"></line>
    <line x1="50"  y1="100" x2="50" y2="37" stroke="blue" stroke-width="50"></line>  
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I was hoping that this code would allow me to display a red bar and a blue bar of equal widths side by side. But it does not, any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line stroke grow both sides. in this case i think you must use rect instead lines.

```
<svg width="150" height="250">
<rect width="50" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="red"/>
<rect width="50" height="100" x="50" y="0" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

See [this running demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h061s9pp/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Because the stroke-width goes in both directions (left and right) from the center and part of the red rectangle lies outside the borders of the canvas. The overlap occurs for the same reason:

```
  <svg width="250" height="250" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <line x1="25"  y1="100" x2="25" y2="37" stroke="red" stroke-width="50"></line>
    <line x1="75"  y1="100" x2="75" y2="37" stroke="blue" stroke-width="50"></line>  
  </svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stdob/7atfz12c/